# Error con el módulo pyodbc: Error de sintaxis (falta operador) en la expresión de consulta 'clientes[index_seleccionado][1]'

Tags: python, base-de-datos, ms-access, pyodbc

Estoy teniendo un error al querer actualizar mi base de datos access mediante el módulo pyodbc. El error lo tira en el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
cursor.execute('''
            UPDATE Inquilinos 
            SET Inquilino = clientes[index_seleccionado][1]
            WHERE Inquilino = nombre_viejo
           ''')
```

Y el error que me tira es el siguiente:

```
File "c:\Users\manue\OneDrive\Escritorio\Programas\Inmo_Management\main_code.py", line 206, in aplicar
    cursor.execute('''
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] Error de sintaxis (falta operador) en la expresión de consulta 'clientes[index_seleccionado][1]'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

clientes[index_seleccionado][1] es un valor de tipo int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente la sentencia SQL es errónea:

```
UPDATE Inquilinos 
       SET Inquilino = clientes[index_seleccionado][1]
       WHERE Inquilino = nombre_viejo
```

Necesitas usar los "placeholders", para reemplazarlos por los datos que efecitvamente llegan desde tu código:

```
datos = [clientes[index_seleccionado][1], nombre_viejo]
cursor.execute('''
            UPDATE Inquilinos 
            SET Inquilino = ?
            WHERE Inquilino = ?
           ''', datos)
```

Creamos una lista, con los elementos que usará la sentencia SQL y en esta última, indicamos con `?` los lugares dónde se completaran los datos.